# DispatchToProps() method in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been going through some react - redux code and I'm stuck on the below code snippet

```
const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
    addComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(addComment(dishId, rating, author, comment))
 })
```

I'm not that experienced in Javascript so it would be good to get a clarification on what this mapDispatchToProps method is accomplishing.

I know what this method is, I'm just confused on the Javascript part

Comment: are you concat  your component  as this  connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` is the second argument of the `connect` function in redux.  `mapStateToProps` is the first.  You define `mapDispatchToProps` as a function of `dispatch`, which returns an object.  The syntax `const something = dispatch => ({ ... })` is a shorthand for an arrow function which returns an object.  It is almost the same as

```js
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    addComment: (dishId, ...) => dispatch(addComment(dishId, ...))
  }
}
```

When you feed `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect`, and then wrap your component in that `connect`, it injects the properties and methods of the returned object into the component, as props.  Hence the name `mapXToProps`.  It will usually be used like this:

```js
export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Component)
```

If you don't have a `mapStateToProps`, use `null` in its place. `mapDispatchToProps` allows you to inject your redux actions into your component, so that you can affect the redux store through the props on your component.  `mapStateToProps` is similar - it allows you to grab items from your redux store, and assign them to props on your component.  In your example, you would now be able to access `this.props.addComment` as a prop on your wrapped component.  This is how you connect your components to the redux store, and how you can send and recieve data to the store.

Note that these are just naming conventions. You can actually name these functions whatever you want - but most people use `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, as its pretty descriptive of what's hapenning.  You can name them `puppy` and `booya` for all redux cares, so long as you feed them to `connect` properly.

Obligatory [read the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).  Though to be frank when I was learning this, someone had to actually explain it to me too, but the docs are a great resource.